# Cannot generate allure report from allure docker

Tags: java, docker, selenium, testng, allure

I have tested with testng.xml and got the folder called `allure-results` on my linux host. This folder has many .json files

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  202 Jan 27 03:20 038526c0-e53c-4907-a04b-7061eff12e91-container.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  548 Jan 27 03:20 17bd74ad-1f5e-4ef9-9f21-b2ec85cfca47-container.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  419 Jan 27 03:20 1bd85195-ab0d-4e17-ab12-800e5037405f-container.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  195 Jan 27 03:20 1f6a2505-8c58-452d-a564-e7ffa9512599-container.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  837 Jan 27 03:20 4fb8431a-162a-4f33-889b-2e5ee5c01843-result.json
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root  415 Jan 27 03:20 990031d8-60eb-4379-8864-aee237fed175-container.json
```

The docker-compose file I used to create a container is as below.

```
version: '2'
services:
  allure:
    image: "frankescobar/allure-docker-service"
    environment:
      CHECK_RESULTS_EVERY_SECONDS: 1
      KEEP_HISTORY: 1
    ports:
      - "5050:5050"
    volumes:
      - $PROJECT_PATH/allure-results:/app/allure-results
      - $PROJECT_PATH/allure-reports:/app/default-reports
```

The project name I created in allure-docker is `test`.

To generate allure report, I request this URL.
`http://192.168.100.58:5050/allure-docker-service/generate-report?project_id=test` but got nothing in there.

I can see the same .json files in the container's path as they are correctly mounted as a volume.

```
allure@0ff7067fedb0:/app/allure-results$ ll
total 36
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root   4096 Jan 27 03:20 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 allure allure 4096 Dec 14 10:03 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    202 Jan 27 03:20 038526c0-e53c-4907-a04b-7061eff12e91-container.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    548 Jan 27 03:20 17bd74ad-1f5e-4ef9-9f21-b2ec85cfca47-container.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    419 Jan 27 03:20 1bd85195-ab0d-4e17-ab12-800e5037405f-container.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    195 Jan 27 03:20 1f6a2505-8c58-452d-a564-e7ffa9512599-container.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    837 Jan 27 03:20 4fb8431a-162a-4f33-889b-2e5ee5c01843-result.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root   root    415 Jan 27 03:20 990031d8-60eb-4379-8864-aee237fed175-container.json
allure@0ff7067fedb0:/app/allure-results$
```

**Question** What am I missing to get the allure report?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself.
To generate a report, actually, I don't have to generate it manually as this allure-docker generates reports automatically if new results in the results directory are detected.

To get the report, remove `allure-docker-service` from URL request. Hence, it should be like,

`http://192.168.100.58:5050/generate-report?project_id=test`